# Oracle fetch returns more than requested

Tags: oracle, plsql

So I've got another simple procedure with an error.  This time, the fetch is returning more records than requested.  I initially checked my query and found an error.  My query returns the right results, but the fetch still won't work.
PROCEDURE:

```
--View Customer Service History
create or replace procedure SERVICEHISTORY(name in customer.name%type) is

carModel char(11);
serviceCharge decimal(7,2);
serviceName char(20);
serviceDate date;
cusName char(15);
cusID number;



--Query tested, it works
cursor nextService is
select name, workOrder.serviceDate, workOrderServices.actualCharge
from workOrder join workOrderServices on workOrder.workOrderID=workOrderServices.workOrderID join services on workOrderServices.serviceID=services.serviceID
where workOrderServices.customerID=cusID;

begin
--Get customer ID from name, another janky work around
select customerID
into cusID
from customer
where customer.name=name;

--Gets the car model
select model
into carModel
from vehicle
where vehicle.customerID=cusID;

open nextService;
fetch nextService into serviceName, serviceDate, serviceCharge;
if nextService%notfound then
    dbms_output.put_line('No service history found.');
else
    dbms_output.put_line('Service-------Date-------Cost');
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(serviceName||'  '||serviceDate||'  '||serviceCharge);
        fetch nextService into serviceName, serviceDate, serviceCharge;
        if nextService%notfound then
            dbms_output.put_line('Report finished.');
        end if;
    exit when nextService%notfound;
    end loop;
end if;
close nextService;
end serviceHistory;
/
```

But it throws this error:

```
ERROR: 
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at line 20
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Here are the tables:

```
create table customer
    (
        customerID number(8) not null primary key constraint lengthCHK13 check(LENGTH(customerID)=8),
        name varchar2(20) not null,
        address varchar2(20) not null,
        insurance varchar2(20) not null,
        contactInfo number(10) not null,
        customerType varchar2(15) not null,
        licenseNumber varchar2(13) not null,
        amountOwed decimal(7,2) not null constraint notNeg6 check(amountOwed >=0)
    );

create table vehicle
    (
        --some error about no matching unique or primary key for this column on cusomterID
        VIN varchar2(17) not null primary key constraint lengthCHK113 check(length(VIN)=17),
        customerID number(8) not null references customer(customerID) constraint lengthCHK12 check(length(customerID)=8),
        make varchar2(10) not null,
        model varchar2(10) not null,
        carYear number(4) not null,
        color varchar2(10) not null,
        notes varchar2(20),
        currentMileage number(6) not null,
        engineType varchar2(10) not null,
        licenseNumber varchar(12) not null,
        amountOwed decimal(7,2) constraint notNeg7 check(amountOwed >=0)
        --primary key(VIN, customerID) DOESNT WORK BUT NEEDS TO
    );

create table workOrder
    (
        workOrderID number(8) not null constraint lengthCHK10 check(length(workOrderID)=8),
        VIN varchar2(17) not null references vehicle(VIN) constraint lengthCHK14 check(length(VIN)=17),
        serviceDate date not null,
        --Removing b/c it's a pain serviceTime TIME not null,
        serviceBay number(2),
        description varchar2(20) not null,
        results varchar2(20) not null,
        primary key(workOrderID)
    );

create table services
    (
        serviceID number(8) not null primary key constraint lengthCHK17 check(length(serviceID)=8),
        name varchar2(20) not null,
        price decimal(7,2) not null constraint notNeg8 check(price >=0),
        estimatedHours number(2) not null
    );

create table workOrderServices
    (
        serviceID number(8) not null references services(serviceID) constraint lengthCHK20 check(length(serviceID)=8),
        workOrderID number(8) not null references workOrder(workOrderID) constraint lengthCHK22 check(length(workOrderID)=8),
        customerID number(8) not null references customer(customerID) constraint lengthCHK87 check(length(customerID)=8),
        actualHours number(2) not null constraint notNeg11 check(actualHours >=0),
        actualCharge decimal(7,2) not null constraint notNeg10 check(actualCharge >=0),
        primary key(serviceID, workOrderID)
    );
```

Test data:

```
INSERT INTO services(serviceID, name, price, estimatedHours)
VALUES(48937322, 'Tire Rotate', 19.99, 1);
INSERT INTO services(serviceID, name, price, estimatedHours)
VALUES(47873231, 'Xmission Flush', 63.99, 1);
INSERT INTO customer (customerID, name, address, insurance, contactInfo, customerType, licenseNumber, amountOwed)
VALUES (45124512, 'Bob Jones',  '232 Sycamore Ln.', 'Pekin', 3095555145, 'New', 'SSSSFFFYYDDD', 220.00);
INSERT INTO customer (customerID, name, address, insurance, contactinfo, customertype, licensenumber, amountOwed)
VALUES (12892222, 'Mike Tyson','100 Haters Rd.', 'Progressive', 2175555555, 'Regular', 'FGHJHHHHTYYY', 42.00);

INSERT INTO vehicle(VIN, customerID, make, model, carYear, color, notes, currentMileage, engineType, licenseNumber, amountOwed)
VALUES('KNDKG3A31A7568300', 45124512, 'Ford', 'Focus', 2009, 'Red',  'side door damage', 10346, 'V4', 'h5303h87dk23', 0);
INSERT INTO vehicle(VIN, customerID, make, model, carYear, color, notes, currentMileage, engineType, licenseNumber, amountOwed)
VALUES('SALTW16413A376838', 12892222, 'Chrysler', 'Sebring', 2004, 'Green', 'Basically a Go-Kart', 105098, 'V4', 'r2345h23tx31', 0);

INSERT INTO workOrder( workOrderID, VIN, serviceDate, serviceBay, description, results)
VALUES(12312312, 'KNDKG3A31A7568300', '07-FEB-12', 2, 'Oil Change', 'Changed oil'); 
INSERT INTO workOrder( workOrderID, VIN, serviceDate, serviceBay, description, results)
VALUES(32132132, 'SALTW16413A376838', '07-FEB-12', 3,'Tire Rotation', 'Rotated the tires');

INSERT INTO workOrderServices(serviceID, workOrderID, customerID, actualHours, actualCharge)    
VALUES(17278722, 12312312, 45124512, 5,  45.00);
INSERT INTO workOrderServices(serviceID, workOrderID, customerID,actualHours, actualCharge)
VALUES(48937322, 32132132, 12892222,10, 90.00);
```

Comment: one of the select-into returns more than one row

Comment: @BobJarvis - the sample set reproduces the problem.  It's a code bug not a data issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had put some extra messaging into your code, as I did, you would have quickly discovered the source of the error.

```
create or replace procedure SERVICEHISTORY(name in customer.name%type) is

carModel char(11);
serviceCharge decimal(7,2);
serviceName char(20);
serviceDate date;
cusName char(15);
cusID number;



--Query tested, it works
cursor nextService is
select name, workOrder.serviceDate, workOrderServices.actualCharge
from workOrder 
    join workOrderServices 
    on workOrder.workOrderID=workOrderServices.workOrderID 
    join services on workOrderServices.serviceID=services.serviceID
where workOrderServices.customerID=cusID;

begin
dbms_output.put_line('Get customer ID from name, another janky work around');
select customerID
into cusID
from customer
where customer.name=name;
dbms_output.put_line('cusID='||cusID);
--Gets the car model
select model
into carModel
from vehicle
where vehicle.customerID=cusID;
dbms_output.put_line('carModel='||carModel);

open nextService;
fetch nextService into serviceName, serviceDate, serviceCharge;
if nextService%notfound then
    dbms_output.put_line('No service history found.');
else
    dbms_output.put_line('Service-------Date-------Cost');
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(serviceName||'  '||serviceDate||'  '||serviceCharge);
        fetch nextService into serviceName, serviceDate, serviceCharge;
        if nextService%notfound then
            dbms_output.put_line('Report finished.');
        end if;
    exit when nextService%notfound;
    end loop;
end if;
close nextService;
end serviceHistory;
/
```

Here's my output:

```
SQL> exec SERVICEHISTORY(name=>'Bob Jones')
Get customer ID from name, another janky work around
BEGIN SERVICEHISTORY(name=>'Bob Jones'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "APC.SERVICEHISTORY", line 23
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

It's the very first query which hurls.  Why does it do that?  Because you've given the parameter the same name as the column.  In PL/SQL variable naming has scope, with the nearest declaration trumping further ones.

So in your query ...

```
select customerID
into cusID
from customer
where customer.name=name;
```

... Oracle interprets `name` on the right-hand side as being the column of the table, *because that's the narrowest scope*.  Effectively your filter is `where 1=1`, which is no filter at all.

All you need to do to fix this is change the parameter to something like `p_name` and use that in your query instead...

```
SQL> exec SERVICEHISTORY(p_name=>'Mike Tyson')
Get customer ID from name, another janky work around
cusID=12892222
carModel=Sebring
Service-------Date-------Cost
Tire Rotate           07-FEB-12  90
Report finished.

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

---

Of course, you will get the same error from the query on VEHICLE should you customer have more than one car, which the data model supports.

At the moment you don't use the result from that query, so the easiest fix would be to remove it.  But probably you want to include it in the output, so the best solution might be to include VEHICLE in the main query.

Comment: Since oracle allows name to be used as a parameter name how will it distinguish between parameter name and column name

Comment: In a SQL statement it will always resolve any ambiguity in favour of a column name.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This procedure is due tomorrow and you saved my group's skin.  We won't have to present a broken procedure now!

Comment: You're welcome.  By the way, I don't recommend using DBMS_OUTPUT as a diagnostic tool - logging to a  table or remote debugging are better.  But whichever approach you take, comprehensiveness is the key.